# The application has stopped unexpectedly android studio (Settext Error)

Tags: android

I have a problem the application has stopped unexpectedly android studio when I use settext. Can you help me.

```
package net.android.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class phuongtrinhb1 extends Activity {
Button giaibt;
    EditText nhapa,nhapb,ketqua;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phuongtrinhb1);
        giaibt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.giaibt);
        nhapa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nhapa);
        nhapb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nhapb);

        giaibt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double a,b;
                a = Double.parseDouble(nhapa.getText().toString());
                b = Double.parseDouble(nhapb.getText().toString());

ketqua.setText("Test x ="+(-b/a));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where initializing `ketqua` EditText?

Comment: See the errors and at least try to fix them, before posting on stack

Comment: Its quite obvious debug your code and you will get to know what mistakes you have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not intialised the EditText ketqua:

example

```
ketqua = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ketqua);
```

Comment: ;) i did :) Can you share me your facebook address or contact information :)